# split a string according to pattern in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a list of strings as follows:

```
a <- c("aaaa 12 comments","bb cc 124 dd 134 commments","hh tt hhh 17 comments")
```

I would like to create two vectors, one which contains only the text and one which contains only the number of comments.

The number of comments can be different but it is always listed at the end.

Desired result:

```
a1 <- c("aaaa","bb cc 124 dd","hh tt hhh")
a2 <- c("12 comments","134 commments","17 comments")
```

Any help is much appreciated. I am trying with gsub, but it is not working:

```
> gsub('[:digit:]*[:space:]comments$','', a)
[1] "aaaa 12 comments"           "bb cc 124 dd 134 commments" "hh tt hhh 17 comments"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
a1 <- gsub('([0-9]+ comments$)',"", a)
library(stringr)
a2 <- unlist(str_extract_all(a,'([0-9]+ comments$)'))
```

Comment: I am just wondering why for the second operation I need a different function? Is there a way to achieve it with gsub by using an exception, for example like this: (which does not work)                                                                                              a2 <- gsub("^[([0-9]+ comments$)]"," ", a)

Comment: gsub is for replacing the matched pattern, str_extract extracts the text matching our pattern.

Comment: I understand, thanks, but I am just wondering why my statement does not work to instruct gsub to delete everything in the string except the number of comments?

Comment: You're welcome. your statement actually means : "Replace the substrings that match the given pattern "^[([0-9]+ comments$)]" by "" ". So you're doing the opposite, keeping everything except the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the explanations, I really appreciate it. I am still a bit confused why the symbol " ^ " does not work in my expression to indicate that the phrase should be an exception.

Comment: ^ in regex means, the expression should be at the start of the string, not negation .

Comment: thanks, I think I understand now. Still a lot to learn though.Thanks for your help!